# How to add square border in xaml

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am working on the xamarin forms and using the xaml to make the UI.

[image]

Please see the aboveimage and let me know how to draw this in xaml and in the image number is dynamic

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Frame](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Frame/), here is a simple example:

```
<Frame OutlineColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Label Text="{Binding MyNumber}" TextColor="White" />
</Frame>
```

The outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `AbsoluteLayout` and just use an image (or better a svg) on top of which you add a `Label` bound to your `int` value.